# Can't build docker image (requirements.txt install pymssql error)

Tags: docker

I want to up flask app with a container on AWS App Runner but when I creating Docker Images I getting error. In requirements.txt file pymssql library importing error.

Here is requirements.txt file:

```
flask
jsonify
pandas
pymssql
numpy
jwt
```

Here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 8081

CMD ["python", "app.py" ]
```

When building Docker images I getting this error

```
#8 12.28   
#8 12.28   × Building wheel for pymssql (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
#8 12.28   │ exit code: 1
#8 12.28   ╰─> [25 lines of output]
#8 12.28       setup.py: platform.system() => Linux
#8 12.28       setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
#8 12.28       setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.31')
#8 12.28       setup.py: include_dirs => []
#8 12.28       setup.py: library_dirs => []
#8 12.28       running bdist_wheel
#8 12.28       running build
#8 12.28       running build_py
#8 12.28       creating build
#8 12.28       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
#8 12.28       creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pymssql
#8 12.28       copying src/pymssql/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/pymssql
#8 12.28       running build_ext
#8 12.28       cythoning src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx to src/pymssql/_mssql.c
#8 12.28       cythoning src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx to src/pymssql/_pymssql.c
#8 12.28       building 'pymssql._mssql' extension
#8 12.28       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310
#8 12.28       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src
#8 12.28       creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/pymssql
#8 12.28       gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c src/pymssql/_mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-cpython-310/src/pymssql/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
#8 12.28       src/pymssql/_mssql.c:747:10: fatal error: sqlfront.h: No such file or directory
#8 12.28         747 | #include "sqlfront.h"
#8 12.28             |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
#8 12.28       compilation terminated.
#8 12.28       error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
#8 12.28       [end of output]
#8 12.28   
#8 12.28   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#8 12.28   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymssql
#8 12.28 Successfully built jsonify
#8 12.28 Failed to build pymssql
#8 12.28 ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymssql, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
#8 12.28 
#8 12.28 [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.2 -> 22.3.1
#8 12.28 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code:
```

Comment: As the error state, you are missing _sqlfront.h_, which you can install with the package [freetds-dev](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sqlfront.h&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any)

Comment: Do I need to specify this package in dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, indeed, with a `RUN`, a bit like this one: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#sort-multi-line-arguments

Comment: Please do not post images of text; post the text itself formatted as a code sample. This makes your question much easier to read, more accessible to people using assistive devices like screen readers, and is tremendously helpful when someone wants to copy-and-paste portions of your question while working on an answer.